# svnserve with LDAP

Tags: svn, ldap, svnserve

I would like to know how to setup an SVN repository with LDAP authentication.
I do not want to use Apache DAV though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Run svnserve as a server, and authenticate using [SASL](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/sasl.txt). Configure [SASL to authenticate against LDAP](https://web.archive.org/web/20140528175339/http://www.imc.org:80/ietf-sasl/mail-archive/msg01862.html).
2. Access the repository over ssh. Create ssh accounts for all users (perhaps automatically), and have these accounts authenticate against LDAP using PAM. Put all users into a single group, and make the repository files owned by that group.

Comment: Any clue on how to do option 1 on a Windows box?

Comment: broken link "SASL to authenticate against LDAP"

Answer (score 9):

Since it took me some time to find the pieces to do this, I wanted to post how I did this on a RHEL5 server:

1. install CollabNet rpms ([client](http://www.open.collab.net/downloads/subversion/linux.html), [server, and extras](http://www.open.collab.net/downloads/subversion/linux-other.html)).
2. run `/opt/CollabNet_Subversion/bin/Configure-CollabNet-Subversion` to configure without Apace and with svnserve.
3. modify your `repo/conf/svnserve.conf` file to have:

   ```
   [sasl]
   use-sasl=true
   ```
4. create `/opt/CollabNet_Subversion/etc/saslauthd.conf` file with these contents:

   ```
   ldap_servers: ldaps://...
   ldap_search_base: ...
   ldap_bind_dn: ...
   ldap_bind_pw: ...
   ldap_auth_method: bind
   ldap_timeout: 10
   ```
5. create `/etc/opt/CollabNet_Subversion/sasl2/svn.conf` file with these contents for use with MS AD LDAP:

   ```
   pwcheck_method: saslauthd
   auxprop_plugin: ldap
   mech_list: PLAIN LOGIN
   ldapdb_mech: PLAIN LOGIN
   ```
6. copy `/etc/openldap/ldap.conf` to `/etc/opt/CollabNet_Subversion/conf/openldap` and add `TLS_REQCERT allow`.  This is required for our self-signed LDAP server
7. run collabnet saslauthd

   - `mkdir -p /var/state/saslauthd`
   - edit `/etc/init.d/collabnet_subversion` to include `/opt/CollabNet_Subversion/sbin/saslauthd -a ldap` towards end of `start()` function
   - `stop/start /etc/init.d/collabnet_subverison`

note: you can use `/opt/CollabNet_Subversion/sbin/testsaslauthd -u <userid> -p <password>` to test sasl connection to ldap

A bit involved, but for me, it allows our clients to connect to `svn://` using their ldap passwords.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [scm-manager](https://bitbucket.org/sdorra/scm-manager) which has an ldap plugin.